# scanpy/python : get the proprotion of cells per cluster for each group

Tags: python, bar-chart

I have two groups ('Average' and 'High') of samples. I have the leiden cluster information.
I want to get a stacked bar chart for each group with the proportion of cells in each leiden cluster. To be as clear as possible i want two bar chart, one for 'Average' and one for 'High', with each color representing a proportion of the cells of the groups coming from each of the leiden cluster.
It might be easy but I don't really know how to achieve this.

For now i just get a dataframe with a first column "group" (with two possible value, Average or High), the second column is the number of the Leiden cluster (eventually the Cell type) and a third with the percentage

[image]

THe plot should look like that (With Average and High instead of Treated Untreated):

[image]

If you know how to do that please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

For people interested here is the solution i found:

```
 cell_proportion_df = pd.crosstab(adata.obs['leiden'],adata.obs['risk'], normalize='columns').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```